# Verbatim-like context in a regular expression

Tags: python, regex, escaping

**Question:**

Is there any way to tell a regular expression engine to treat a certain part of a regular expression as *verbatim* (i.e. look for that part exactly as it is, without the usual parsing) without manually escaping special characters?

**Some context:**

I'm trying to backreference a group on a given regular expression from another regular expression. For instance, suppose I want to match `hello(.*?)olleh` against text 1 and then look for `bye$1eyb` in text 2, where `$1` will be replaced by whatever matched group 1 in text 1. Therefore, if text 1 happens to contain the string `"helloFOOolleh"`, the program will look for `"byeFOOeyb"` in text 2.

The above works fine in most cases, but if text 1 were to contain something like `"hello.olleh"`, the program will match not only `"hello.olleh"` but also `"helloXolleh"`, `"hellouolleh"`, etc. in text 2, as it is interpreting `.` as a regex special character and not the plain dot character.

**Additional comments:**

I can't just search for the plain string resulting from parsing `$1` into whatever group 1 matches, as whatever I want to search for in text 2 could itself contain other unrelated regular expressions.

I have been trying to avoid parsing the match returned from text 1 and escape every single special character, but if anyone knows of a way to do that neatly that could also work.

I'm currently working on this in Python, but if it can be done easily with any other language/program I'm happy to give it a try.

Comment: If you're open to other languages, you might want to try Perl or PHP/PCRE which support inner quoting `\Q..\E`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) function to escape the text you want to match literally.  So after you extract your match text (e.g., "." in "hello.olleh"), apply `re.escape` to it before inserting it into your second regex.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate what BrenBarn wrote,

```
import re

text1 = "hello.olleh"

text2_match   = "bye.eyb"
text2_nomatch = "byeXeyb"

found = re.fullmatch(r"hello(.*?)olleh", text1).group(1)
```

You can then make a new search with the `re.escape`:

```
new_search = "bye{}eyb".format(re.escape(found))
```

Tests:

```
re.search(new_search, text2_match)
#>>> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='bye.eyb'>

re.search(new_search, text2_nomatch)
#>>> None
```